# Bijection from projective space to a set of matrices

Tags: geometry, functions

Let $M$ be the set of $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ symmetric, idempotent matrices of trace 1. What is the inverse function of $f:\mathbb{R}P^n\rightarrow M$ defined by
$[x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}]\mapsto\left(\frac{x_ix_j}{\sum x_k^{2}}\right)$?

Comment: [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1582652/272127)

Answer (score 2):

The inverse function you want maps each such matrix to its image (its column space, if you like), which is a $1$-dimensional subspace, that is, a point of the projective space.