# Grassmannian, symmetric, idempotent matrices of trace $n$?

Tags: general-topology, matrices, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

How do I see that $G_n(\mathbb{R}^m)$ is diffeomorphic to the smooth manifold consisting of all $m \times m$ symmetric, idempotent matrices of trace $n$?

Comment: For starters, do you have a geometric interpretation of an idempotent matrix? A _symmetric_ idempotent matrix...?

Comment: This seems curious as it would make $G_n(\mathbb{R}^m)$ an affine variety.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2275203/272127)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An idenpotent symmetric matrix of trace $n$ is nothing else but an orthogonal projector onto a subspace of dimension $n$. This gives a bijection between these matrices, and $n$ dimensional subspaces of $\bf R^m$, i.e. the Grassmanian.

Comment: Do you by any chance have a reference where I can read about this statement?

Comment: Idenpotent matrix of trace $n$ = projection onto an $n$dimensional space is certainly explained in every textbook on linear algebra. The fact that the projection is othorgonal iff the matrix is symmetric  follows form the formula $<PX,Y>= <X, P^tY>$ (exercise)